# Dual boot Windows 7, Ubuntu 14.04 - can not load Windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows, windows-7

Good evening,
after installing Ubuntu 14.04 as a dual boot with till now working windows 7, I can not boot windows. When I try to, a black screen appears and tells me to insert the windows installation disc to repair it and follow another 2 instructions (but I bought my computer with pre installed Windows, so I can not go this way).
It also says:

```
File: \Boot\BCD
Status: 0xc0000034
The windows boot configuration data is missing required information
```

I already tried boot repair through Ubuntu twice, but it didn't work. (Here are the links: http://paste.ubuntu.com/8581328/, http://paste.ubuntu.com/8581369/). 
The Windows OS still seems to be on the disc. 
Please tell me what can I do to be able to access windows again...

Answer (score 0):

The error says that the windows Boot Configuration is missing. To repair the Boot Configuration Data (BCD), you need to use the bootrec.exe tool from Windows Recovery Environment.

The Windows Recovery Environment can be loaded by booting from a Windows 7 disk. In case you don't have a disk, you can download one and use. Using it to recover your BCD doesn't affect your license (Look at the comments [here](https://superuser.com/questions/828395/does-recovering-from-a-different-windows-disk-affect-your-license)).

**How to run the Bootrec.exe tool:**

To run the Bootrec.exe tool, first start the Windows RE:

1. Put the Windows Vista or Windows 7 media in the DVD drive, and then start the computer.
2. Press a key when you are prompted.
3. Select a language, a time, a currency, a keyboard, or an input method, and then click Next.
4. Click Repair your computer.
5. Select the operating system that you want to repair, and then click Next.
6. In the System Recovery Options dialog box, click Command Prompt.
7. Type Bootrec.exe, and then press Enter.

Bootrec.exe options:

- /FixMbr
- /FixBoot
- /ScanOs
- /RebuildBcd

This information has been taken from [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! 
Well, I do have a partition on the hard disc which is designed like a recovery tool, but I don't have a disc to put in optical disc drive. Do you think it is possible to use this partition somehow? And will the data I have on Windows stay?

Comment: Now, I have tried the recovery tool from the partition. A light blue windows 7 screen appears (with a rather low resolution) and then it says something like "unvalid entries :recovery PartitionIndex==bootPartition" and then the computer turns itself off. What is interesting is, that it seems it's starting like "Windows Vista", though my computer has nothing in common with this OS. 
All the Support articles I've read still instruct "Put the Windows 7 media in the DVD drive, and then start the computer.", which I obviously can not do. Please, help me!

Comment: Do you have the option of downloading a trial edition of Windows and then recovering using it?

Comment: That is an interesting idea, but won't it somehow affect my Winodws 7 license? (I mean, won't it rewrite the pre-installed full version and then after month or so expire?) I am also affraid, whether it won't someow affect the files, programmes or settings I have installed (I mean, the serial number or whatever won't be the same, will it?) And, finally, will it be able to run the repair tool? Won't it just install another OS?

Comment: I assumed it won't but I'm not sure and still trying to find out. Different people have different things to say. Look at my question on superuser and the comments below it http://superuser.com/questions/828395/does-recovering-from-a-different-windows-disk-affect-your-license

Comment: Thank you very much, I will watch the answers closely! I'm just still a bit unsure about how to use the repair tool. Will it be automatically available after going to BIOS and choosing optical/USB drive? I mean, will the OS installation automatically find out that I already have windows installed and I just need to repair the boot? (That means, will the repair tool be the first thing to launch, of will I have to search it in some menu?) I'm sorry for my probably silly  questions, but I already made a big mistake by ruining the boot, so I don't want to end up doing something even worse...

Comment: It will not automatically find out that you need to repair but you need to choose `repair`. The link provided in the answer above explains the step by step instructions on how to fix your BCD using a Windows 7 disk.

Comment: Ok, now I get it! So when I insert the disc, I can choose "repair" from some menu and run it, isn't it? That's great! I was afraid, that it would start installing automatically without giving me any options. Thank you very, very much for your help, I honestly appreciate it! When I'm done repairing the boot, I will write here how it has turned out, in case if someone had once the same problem.

Comment: So, I'm finally writing from Windows! The Installation went quite well, though now I can't boot to Ubuntu. But the main thing is, that Windows is finally working again and all the data is safe and didn't notice anything missing, so I am really happy, though all the work seems a bit lost now, whan I am where I was a week ago - having a computer only running Windows...
Thank you, Chintan, for your help, it meant, and still means, a lot to me, that you were willing to help me with this!!

Comment: Well then, I've updated the answer to include the required information. If it worked for you, it might work for someone else too. So, it'd be great if you accepted this answer.